# Android add fragment and tab after load?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity with two Fragments in it and a sliding tab layout:

```
String titles[] = new String[] {"Tab One", "Tab Two"};
int numTabs = titles.length;

EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles, numTabs);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

SlidingTabLayout sliding_tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
sliding_tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

With the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
private class EventAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<String> titles;
    private int numTabs;

    public void addTab (String title) {
        this.titles.add(title);
        this.numTabs++;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public EventAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> mTitles, int mNumTabs) {
        super(fm);

        this.titles = mTitles;
        this.numTabs = mNumTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 2:
                return new FragThree();
            case 1:
                return new FragTwo();
            default:
                return new FragOne();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numTabs;
    }
}
```

Some time down the line, I would like to dynamically add the third tab to this layout. Is there a way to do this in code? As you can see, I already have the PagerAdapter set up to catch the third tab. I just need to load it in...

Comment: [This may help you.](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/03/viewpager-example-with-switching-page.html)

Comment: @MD I didn't see anything there about adding tabs to the pager...

Comment: Did you see `addTab(...)` function in `TabsAdapter` ?

Comment: Can you add your `getCount` method of `FragmentPagerAdapter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this method to your adapter EventAdapter :

```
public void addTab (String title) {
    this.titles.add(title);
    // this is the variable returned from getCount method
    this.numbTabs++;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Main purpose is to add the tab and call notifydatasetchanged. 
Now call addTab on this adapter's object and tab will be added.
after addTab do sliding_tab.setViewPager(this.pager);
 Please accept if this solves the purpose.

Comment: addTab should be called with addTab(titles[3]) or whichever index is your string present at in titles. I think you are sending array of strings in addTab() that's why this error is there

Comment: got the problem. You need to do this.sliding_tabs.setViewPager(this.pager);

Comment: That worked... I guess I need to set the viewpager everytime a new tab is added?